# PHP - register_shutdown_function executes automatically?

Tags: php

```
function fatal_error_handler() {
    if ($error = error_get_last()) {

        switch ($error['type']) {
            case E_ERROR:
                $code = 'FATAL ERROR';
                break;
            case E_CORE_ERROR:
                $code = 'CORE ERROR';
                break;
            case E_CORE_WARNING:
                $code = 'CORE WARNING';
                break;
            default:
                $code = 'UNKNOWN FATAL ERROR';
        }

        echo 'An error occurred (Test 1): ' . $code . '<br />';
    }

    echo 'An error occurred (Test 2): ' . $code . '<br />';
}

register_shutdown_function('fatal_error_handler');
```

I'm currently writing a fatal error handler using the register_shutdown_function. Just wondering, is the register_shutdown_function supposed to run/execute automatically? I've been testing just this block of code above. I've deliberately put in the second echo statement to see if it does run automatically and it does in fact print out the second echo statement (The first echo statement is not printed since there are no fatal errors in place).

Comment: Yes this function will run automatically on shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others state this will run on shutdown whether or not the script finished normally or abnormally due to an error as you realised since you are using this for error handling which it is kinda useful for.

You will even have all the objects you previously created like static classes etc and it can output to browser as you noted.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, this is intentional:](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) (emphasis mine)

> Registers a callback to be executed **after script execution finishes** or exit() is called.